# Jquery Ajax call path

Tags: jquery, ajax, path, call

I need some solution to give relative path in my jquery ajax call as of now I am using soem thing like ../   . Any suggestions would be higly appreaciated.

Code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '../../MyPage/getDetails',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data > 0) {
```

Comment: The path should be relative to the url you see in browser not to the javascript file

Comment: Are you sure the path ends with `getDetails` i.e. without any extension?

Comment: Imdad getDetails is a controller method

Comment: OK, just confirming if it is not a silly mistake. sometimes it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you are client side so :)

This code makes some assumptions - like that the script tage for `myscript.js` exists

Assume you have some markup on your page like so:\

```
<script src='../js/myscript.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>hiya</div>
```

OK, now we will use the script tag and get the base url from that :)

Let's create a Util class we can use, add a get base url method and alert that value:

Working copy here:  http://jsfiddle.net/SmCLy/

```
function Util() { /*...Nothing...*/
}

Util.getBaseURL = function() {
    //<summary>
    //    Returns the application base URL (well, a URL that is
    //    equivalent to such - it may have some "backtracking", 
    //    i.e. "../" at
    //    the end of the URL to simulate the root...)
    //</summary>    
    // 1) Find the script include for this JavaScript file:
    var scriptElements = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
        getScriptPathFragmentPosition = Util.getBaseURL._getScriptPathFragmentPosition,
        getScriptPathFragmentPositionResult = getScriptPathFragmentPosition(scriptElements, "js/myscript.js"),
        posScriptPathFragment = getScriptPathFragmentPositionResult.posScriptPathFragment;

    // 2) Create the "base" URL by taking the current URL,
    // stripping the page from the end, and appending
    // sufficient "../" sequences to
    // construct the equivalent of the application's root URL:
    var scriptElementSrcLower = getScriptPathFragmentPositionResult.scriptElementSrcLower;
    var backPathToRoot = ((scriptElementSrcLower !== "") ? scriptElementSrcLower.substring(0, posScriptPathFragment) : "");
    var currentPath = location.href;
    var currentPathWithoutPage;
    var PAGE_TOKEN = ".aspx";
    var posPageToken = currentPath.toLowerCase().indexOf(PAGE_TOKEN);
    if (posPageToken > -1) {
        var trimmedPath = currentPath.substring(0, posPageToken + PAGE_TOKEN.length);
        currentPathWithoutPage = trimmedPath.substring(0, trimmedPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    } else {
        currentPathWithoutPage = currentPath.substring(0, currentPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }
    return (currentPathWithoutPage + backPathToRoot);
};

Util.getBaseURL._getScriptPathFragmentPosition = function(scriptElements, scriptPathFragment) {
    var scriptElementsIndex = (scriptElements.length - 1),
        scriptElementSrc = "",
        scriptElementSrcLower = "",
        posScriptPathFragment = -1;

    while (scriptElementsIndex >= 0) {
        scriptElementSrc = scriptElements[scriptElementsIndex].getAttribute("src");
        if (typeof(scriptElementSrc) != "undefined" && scriptElementSrc !== null && scriptElementSrc !== "") {
            scriptElementSrcLower = scriptElementSrc.toLowerCase();
            posScriptPathFragment = scriptElementSrcLower.indexOf(scriptPathFragment);

            if (posScriptPathFragment >= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        scriptElementsIndex--;
    }

    var result = {
        posScriptPathFragment: posScriptPathFragment,
        scriptElementSrcLower: scriptElementSrcLower
    };

    return result;
};

alert(Util.getBaseURL());
```

SO, on your page you could do:

```
var myajaxUrl = getBaseURL()+"MyPage/GetDetails";
```

Answer (score 1):

The path you have given is absolutely relative path as long as the hierarchy of your web site remain the same.

The URL you given in ajax call will always move two folder up and call the getDetails method being defined in MyPage

Answer (score 0):

try this 
define `<?php $site_root="WWW.example.com/"  ?>`

```
var URL="<?php echo $site_root;?>folder/your_action.php";
```

and trigger Ajax call